# Is there any efficient design pattern for cards in a cards game?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have to implement a java card game. There are two types of cards with similar effects. The problem is that there are 30 cards. Is there an efficient design pattern (factory, decorator, ecc) to avoid creating a specific class for every card? The cards effects are parsed from Json file or from XML file.

Comment: It really depends on the properties that each card needs. 

Is a generic class 'Card' enough? What makes a card different from the next card?

Comment: The set of solutions is too broad without more information.  The easiest solution given available information is for you to make a single type (Card) with member fields for all possible categories of information: Suit, Number, Special Effect, etc.

Comment: the cards differs only in the effect

Comment: Think about 30 Magic like cards that have different effect and no other properties

Comment: I was thinking about a decorator for a Card class that add the effect described in the  xml or json file for each game card

Comment: Decorator is generally when you wrap an instance of a class and augment it's interface. Sounds like you need more of a factory pattern, or maybe no pattern at all - if you just need a card class with an effect property that is populated from XML then just use a sax parser creating instances of card. If you do need two types of card with different properties according to the effect then parse and call a factory that returns a populated instance of the correct type according to the effect specified in the XML

Comment: I was thinking about the parser but i think i need a patter too because some cards have more than one effect.